# Mock or override a module import in an angular-cli unit test

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

Hi I am using Angular 2 developed with the angular-cli.

I have a simple streaming service that is composed of an imported streaming module. I want to mock the imported module with another mock module but can't figure out how.

My service class is like so

```
import { streaming } from './streaming'

@Injectable()
export class StreamingService {


  constructor() {}

  streaming = streaming;
}
```

And my test is the standard generated test spec file

```
import { streaming } from './streaming'
import { mockStreaming } from './mock-streaming'

    describe('Service: Streaming', () => {
      beforeEach(() => {


        spyOn(streaming);
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          providers: [StreamingService],
          imports: mockStreaming
        })

     });
```

I am wondering should I include the streaming property as a param in the constructor function but I don't want to do it that way.

Is there something I can do in the karma.conf or test.ts file?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `MockStreamingService` which extends `StreamingService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class MockStreamingService {


  constructor() {}
  //And then mock methods, properties etc...
}
```

And then in your test:

```
describe('Service: Streaming', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {


    spyOn(streaming);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{provide:StreamingService, useClass:MockStreamingService}]
    })

 });
```

Comment: I don't think that will work for me

the streaming class I have defined is a simple es6 module i.e.

`let connect = () => {//connect code}

let streaming = { connect: connect}

export streaming`

So I want to knock out the public methods with spies or stubs

Comment: you can use `spyOn` in jasmine to add a spy on a method.If what you want to test is the StreamingService, you shouldn't mock the service itself but its dependencies.